# How to connect to the external server from docker container?

Tags: docker, redis

I have a redis running on my localhost and the docker container which trying connect to that redis, but it cannot do that. I receive this error in terminal:

```
AbortError: Stream connection ended and command aborted. It might have been processed.
```

One way to solve that is to use redis in another container and to link it to my existing container. But I need to have redis running on real host.

Comment: Do the connectivity to an external network or to the host machine is working from the container?

Comment: to the host machine

Comment: so, the issue is with connectivity to the external network only..can you check if the issue is only with ping or DNS. check by ping 8.8.8.8 and google.com from container.

Comment: How are you pointing to redis? Remember that each container has its own localhost.